# Zend Framework Layout Handling

Tags: zend-framework

How is everyone else handing stuff like this?

I'm building a site with ZF, it has 1 layout. Some actions on the site open a ajax or iframe (Fancybox) lightbox to display forms and views. So we need to turn off the layout so the header/background/etc is not displayed, but then I would lose the main body of the layout, like HTML body, Header section with all the default helpers, etc.

In this instances, should I just setup two layouts, or is there a better method to go about handling that?

This is on ZF1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create another layout (let's call it minimal.phtml).
In the controller handling the Ajax you can change the layout script inthe init() function with...

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('minimal');
```

Or

```
 $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('minimal');
```